# How to get current directory name in macros programming?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to know how can i get current directory variable in macros programming. I am saving a file on desktop like this : C:\Users\deadlock\Desktop\data.html. Is it possible to replace the C:\Users\deadlock\Desktop\ with the current directly variable?

Here is my small piece of code:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = True
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
    "C:\Users\deadlock\Desktop\data.htm", "Sheet1", "", xlHtmlStatic, "data_9438", "")
    .Publish (True)
    .AutoRepublish = False
```

Any Code-snippet will highly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current directory is available via VBA's `curdir()` & the directory of the current workbook via `ActiveWorkbook.Path`.

Edit;

```
Dim current As String
current = CurDir$()
'// root dirs have a \ others do not; normalize
If Right$(current, 1) <> "\" Then current = current & "\"

With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
    current & "data.htm", "Sheet1", "", xlHtmlStatic, "data_9438", "")
    .Publish (True)
    ....
```

Comment: can u modify my piece of code to fit your suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to replace the C:\Users\deadlock\Desktop\ with the current directly variable?

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim Myar As Variant

    strPath = "C:\Users\deadlock\Desktop\data.htm"

    Myar = Split(strPath, "\")

    '~~> This would give you something like
    '~~> C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Documents\data.htm
    Debug.Print CurDir & "\" & Myar(UBound(Myar))
End Sub
```