# How to get the browse file path in text box using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

How to get the browse file name into text box ? if get the file path, how to split the file name?

I tried `application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files(*.txt),*.txt")`

Please advise to display into the text box and how to split the exact file name only to read the text file?

Comment: I can give you the answer but if you type `GetOpenFilename` in a VBA Editor and highlight it and then press the magic key `F1` it will give you the code that you need ;)

Comment: Regarding your second question, you can split the path using "\" as a delimiter to extract the file name. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068090/how-to-get-current-directory-name-in-macros-programming/13068192#13068192

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste your time reinventing the wheel: the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will do this for you.

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Sheet1.TextBox1.Text = FSO.GetFilename("C:\mydir\myfile.dat")
```

The textbox now contains the text `myfile.dat`.

Answer (score 3):

The Dir function will give you the file name as long as it's a file that exists - and yours will be if you use GetOpenFilename.

```
Sub GetFileName()

    Dim sFullName As String
    Dim sFileName As String

    sFullName = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.txt,*.txt")
    sFileName = Dir(sFullName)

    Debug.Print sFullName, sFileName

End Sub
```

Comment: How do i set the file to choose all types? can i put ("All files, *.*")?

Comment: `sFullName = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.*,*.*")` will show all file types

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA routine to return the file name stripped of its path.  Its easily modified to return the path instead, or both.

```
'====================================================================================
'     Returns the file name without a path via file open dialog box
'====================================================================================
' Prompts user to select a file.  Which ever file is selected, the function returns
' the filename stripped of the path.

Function GetAFileName() As String

Dim someFileName As Variant
Dim folderName As String
Dim i As Integer
Const STRING_NOT_FOUND As Integer = 0

'select a file using a dialog and get the full name with path included
someFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If someFileName <> False Then

    'strip off the folder path
    folderName = vbNullString
    i = 1

    While STRING_NOT_FOUND < i
        i = InStr(1, someFileName, "\", vbTextCompare)  'returns position of the first backslash "\"
        If i <> STRING_NOT_FOUND Then
            folderName = folderName & Left(someFileName, i)
            someFileName = Right(someFileName, Len(someFileName) - i)
        Else 'no backslash was found... we are done
            GetAFileName = someFileName

        End If
    Wend

Else
    GetAFileName = vbNullString
End If

End Function
```

Comment: i was expecting this answer...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to simply read from the final `"\"`;

```
tbx.text = mid$(someFileName, 1 + InStrRev(someFileName, "\"), Len(someFileName))
```

Answer (score 0):

Button1 click

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
End Sub
```

Textbox1 change

```
    Dim File As System.IO.FileInfo
    File = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim Path As String = File.DirectoryName
    TextBox2.Text = Path
    Dim fileName As String = File.Name
    TextBox3.Text = fileName
End Sub
```